# How to print the output of a command to a toast?

Tags: android, linux, command, su

I'm currently writing a android app that executes su commands and I would like to print the output of that commands to a toast my code looks like this

```
try {

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c rm -rf /data/cache");

} catch (Exception e ) {

}
```

But I found nothing and I have no idea how to do it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by toast?

Comment: sorry i mean this little popup that appears at the bottom i hope you understand it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute shell commands and get output in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608005/execute-shell-commands-and-get-output-in-a-textview)

Answer (score 0):

Save the commands output to a string and Just type Toast and push tab button to auto complete. You can put your text or a string file there. Is this clearing your problem?

Comment: thanks for your answer but is a guide guide for this? i'm pretty new to android applications

Comment: you always have to go to documentation to check first then blogs and then stackoverflow if you are getting doubts

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer on Stack Overflow.

[Get su output into textview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23608939/13685592)

It get the output as a String and set it in a TextView. I think you also can obtain that String and set it as a Toast.