# Print output of PING command as it is running in Android Studio

Tags: android

[Execute shell commands and get output in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608005/execute-shell-commands-and-get-output-in-a-textview)

I found the above solution while searching for answers but this just outputs the result of the ping command for me. My idea is similar to when you are executing PING on command prompt/terminal where you get a line by line output of statistics like latency, etc.

Comment: Use a ping object? There are a variety of ping utilities/frameworks for different languages on different platforms. .net has the [Ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-6.0) class. Oracle has a [Java example too](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/example/Ping.java)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.